# jQuery Flot clear selection

Tags: jquery, selection, flot

Ok, I'm pretty sure once I started using Flot that the "Clear Selection" button on the demo page worked, http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/selection.html. Is it working for any of you? I tried in IE 7/8 and Firefox.

I only noticed this when trying to implement the same functionality in a graph of mine and couldn't get it to work, only to find the examples not working on the demo page...

Here's my code:

```
$.post(applicationPath + "graph/" + action,
    function (data)
    {
        var graphOptions = {
            xaxis: {
                mode: 'time',
                timeformat: "%m/%d/%y"
            },
            yaxis: {
                tickDecimals: 0
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                container: $('.legend')
            },
            series: {
                points: { show: true },
                lines: { show: true }
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            },
            selection: {
                mode: "xy"
            }
        };

        // hard-code color indices to prevent them from shifting as
        // series are turned on/off
        var i = 0;
        $.each(data, function (key, val)
        {
            val.color = i;
            i++;
        });

        var optionsContainer = $('.module.graph .options-menu');

        $.each(data, function (key, val)
        {
            optionsContainer.append('<li><input type="checkbox" name="' + key + '" checked="checked" id="id' + key + '">' + val.label + '</li>');
        });

        $('.module.graph .header .options').optionsMenu(
        {
            sTarget: '.options-menu',
            fnCheckboxSelected: function (index, name)
            {
                $.plot(data, optionsContainer, graphOptions);
            },
            fnCheckboxDeselected: function (index, name)
            {
                $.plot(data, optionsContainer, graphOptions);
            }
        });

        var dataSet = [];

        optionsContainer.find('input:checked').each(function ()
        {
            var key = $(this).attr('name');

            if (key && data[key])
            {
                dataSet.push(data[key]);
            }
        });

        var previousPoint = null;
        var graphContainer = $('.graph #graph-container');

        graphContainer.bind('plothover', function (e, pos, item, ranges)
        {
            if (item)
            {
                if (previousPoint != item.datapoint)
                {
                    previousPoint = item.datapoint;

                    $('#tooltip').remove();

                    var xFormatted = new Date(item.datapoint[0]).toDateString();
                    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2);
                    var y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                    showGraphToolTip(item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + " of " + y + " on " + xFormatted);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $('#tooltip').remove();
                previousPoint = null;
            }
        });

        graphContainer.bind('plotselected', function (event, ranges)
        {
            if (ranges.xaxis.to - ranges.xaxis.from < 0.00001)
            {
                ranges.xaxis.to = ranges.xaxis.from + 0.00001;
            }
            if (ranges.yaxis.to - ranges.yaxis.from < 0.00001)
            {
                ranges.yaxis.to = ranges.yaxis.from + 0.00001;
            }

            $.plot(graphContainer, dataSet,

                $.extend(true, {}, graphOptions,
                {
                    xaxis: { min: ranges.xaxis.from, max: ranges.xaxis.to },
                    yaxis: { min: ranges.yaxis.from, max: ranges.yaxis.to }
                })
            );
        });

        var graph = $.plot(graphContainer, dataSet, graphOptions);

        $('#clearSelection').click(function ()
        {
            graph.clearSelection();
        });
    },
    "json"
);
```

I really can't see anything wrong in my code as it's practically a copy and past from Flot examples, but is there anything glaring here?

Also, is there a possible bug in Flot? Does the clear selection demo work for you?

Comment: The demo link works fine for me. Do you see any js errors in Firebug / Console when it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm actually at another computer now and I still get nothing on the demo. No errors in Firebug also. And just FYI, I am selecting the zoom to selection checkbox and zooming works just fine. What browser are you using? I'm using Firefox 3.6.13 and IE 8. Total weirdness...

Comment: Wow... even tried on my iPhone, but clicking the "Select Year" button because you can't zoom. Clear selection still didn't work...

Comment: lol... I just spoke with a co-worker and I apparently misunderstood the feature completely. I thought the clearSelection function would return the graph back to it's normal state before zooming... which would really make more sense than the literal Clear Selection meaning. Oh well, I've implemented what I wanted... it was good for a laugh though. Go Mondays

Comment: If you could put your last comment as an answer it would be cool, because it would show that it was no longer an open question.  Thanks for coming back to state the resolution, though.

Answer (score 1):

From [flot.googlecode.com](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt)

> - setupGrid()

```
Recalculate and set axis scaling, ticks, legend etc.

Note that because of the drawing model of the canvas, this
function will immediately redraw (actually reinsert in the DOM)
the labels and the legend, but not the actual tick lines because
they're drawn on the canvas. You need to call draw() to get the
canvas redrawn.
```

If you add this to the reset function you should be able to make it work as you expect.